# Release.Name format to be defined and used in pipeline tasks

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I need steps to get Release Name that is defined in Options -> General -> Release Name Format.
how to use this in other variables?
I tried using $(Release.Name) but it didn't work.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you start by looking at the documentation? It's not working because there is no variable named Release.Name. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=batch#default-variables---release

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `Release.ReleaseName`: [Default variables - Release](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=batch#default-variables---release).

> Release.ReleaseName   The name of the current release.
>
> Example: Release-47